# System.Drawing.Printing Drawing String vertically fromRight to Left in rectangle center alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, system.drawing

I want to draw a string in a specified rectangle(vertical direction), Below code gives me wat I am after but the text flow is from Left to Right, What I am trying to is Right to Left. Like Line 1 on the right side and Line 2 is on left side. I did Transformation also, but no luck.

```
 RectangleF tabbor = new RectangleF(0, 0,borHeight, 44.35F);
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        //if (cmbDir.SelectedItem.Equals("Vertical"))
        //    sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        //Do 180 degree Rotatation Transformation
        ev.Graphics.RotateTransform(90, MatrixOrder.Append);                   
        ev.Graphics.TranslateTransform(xPos+44.35F, yPos, MatrixOrder.Append);                    
        ev.Graphics.DrawString("T", printFont, Brushes.Black, tabbor, sf);
        if (cbPreview.Checked)
            ev.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(tabbor));
```

[image] I am looking for the text from top to bottom(now its in reverse), line position right to left(this is working)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing a 180 degree rotation transformation.Check the below code

```
        RectangleF tabbor = new RectangleF(0, 0, 44.35F,150.0F);         
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;            
        String drawString = "First Line Second Line";
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        float x = 0F;
        float y = 0F;
        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
        drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
        //Do 180 degree Rotatation Transformation
        ev.Graphics.RotateTransform(180,MatrixOrder.Append);
        ev.Graphics.TranslateTransform(50, 150,MatrixOrder.Append);
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, Brushes.Black, tabbor,sf);               
        ev.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(tabbor));
```

Comment: Thanks for looking in to, I can see what I expected from your code, however, I have to print on specific location(X,Y ) for each page in continuous cycle,  since I am not getting here co ordinates in negative, Struck in implementing with my code. pls let me know little more info.

Comment: FYI, I am trying to print TAB Dividers. Page height/no. of dividers, then drawing rectangles and drawing string in center in vertical dir. I have to strictly depend on the points, As I see in your logic moving the rectangle to negative co ordinates in X,Y and transforming it. Solution without touching the rectnagle co ordinates I am looking at, the text inside rectangle should transform.

Comment: Set string location to coordinates (0,0) then do the rotation.After the rotation do a transformation (your X+Rectangle Width,Your Y).Check the edited code

Comment: I did exactly as you proposed, but no luck, nt sure where I am missing. I gave transformation and rotation as per you said, The text is out of paper, not seeing anything, Co ordinates are within page, may be transaformation and rotation is keeping out of paper. check my code edited. strtab[0] is text.

Comment: I got it now after I understand about the Rotate transformation. I have edited my code and which is working now. Co ordinates should be (X+width,Y+Height).. Thanks a lot

Comment: ,The direction of the text is changed along with the line position. The reading order should be top to bottom, this gave me bottom to top, due to the transformation everything got reversed. you can check the picture attached.

Comment: After recollecting my school days Geometry, Finally I did achieved. The simple solution without using the Stringformat.VerticalDirection, and with Transformation. Posted the solution.